# SSRS Row grouping how to get the column as a header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

Could any one give an idea how to display the below in SSRS.

[image]

I tried using row grouping and getting the below. please assist how to display same as the first screen shot.
without spacing and getting header part in separate line.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you have a minimum of 2 groupings

Delete the first and second column that has the group value in the tablix.

SSRS will ask you if you want to delete column or the column and the group.

Select the **Column only** and leave the group alone.

Next right click on the detail row and select insert -> row -> outside group (above)

Merge this line and put the second group field in this row  (**6.1 ...** )

Now right click on the merged line and select insert row -> outside group (above)

Merge this line and put the TOP group field in this row  (**Training Area ...** )

Run the report and you should now have what your desired output